# return each variable outside $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, each

I'm a bit new to multidimensional arrays in JSON and I've been banging my head with something for a while now. Let me post my code below

JSON:

```
{
    "easy_questions": [
        {
            "q": "Question 1",
            "a": [
                {"option":"Answer 1",   "correct": false},
                {"option":"Answer 2",   "correct":true},
                {"option":"Answer 3",   "correct":false},
                {"option":"Answer 4", "correct": false}
            ],
            "image": false,
            "source": "dsa"
        }, 
        {
            "q": "Question 2",
            "a": [
                {"option":"Answer 1",   "correct": false},
                {"option":"Answer 2",   "correct":true},
                {"option":"Answer 3",   "correct":false},
                {"option":"Answer 4", "correct": false}
            ],
            "image": false,
            "source": false
        }, // this goes on for about 7 more questions...
    ], 
    "step2_easy": [
        {
            "q": "Question 1",
            "a": [
                {"option":"Answer 1",   "correct": false},
                {"option":"Answer 2",   "correct":true},
                {"option":"Answer 3",   "correct":false},
                {"option":"Answer 4", "correct": false}
            ],
            "image": false,
            "source": false
        },
        {
            "q": "Question 2",
            "a": [
                {"option":"Answer 1",   "correct": false},
                {"option":"Answer 2",   "correct":true},
                {"option":"Answer 3",   "correct":false},
                {"option":"Answer 4", "correct": false}
            ],
            "image": false,
            "source": false
        }, //goes on again
```

And my JavaScript

```
function quizFun() {
    var questions = [];
    var answers = [];
    var quiz = "url.to/questions.json";

    $.getJSON(quiz, function(data) {
        lvl_1(data);
        function lvl_1(data) {
            var easy = data.easy_questions;

            function shuffle(array) {
                var counter = array.length, temp, index;
                    // While there are elements in the array
                    while (counter--) {
                        // Pick a random index
                        index = (Math.random() * counter) | 0;
                        // And swap the last element with it
                        temp = array[counter];
                        array[counter] = array[index];
                        array[index] = temp;
                    }

                    return array;
            }
            var randoms = shuffle(easy.slice(0));
            randoms.length = 3;

            jQuery.each(randoms, function(i, val) {
                var question = val.q,
                    sourse = val.source;
                    img = val.image;
                    answ = val.a;
                    option = null;
                    correct = null;

                $.each(answ,function(option, correct) {
                    option = this.option;
                    correct = this.correct;
                    answers = '<span data-true="'+correct+'">'+option+'</span>';

                    return answers;

                });
                if(!img) {
                    html_strucutre = question + answers;
                } else {
                    html_strucutre = question + '<img src="'+img+'" width="300">' + answers;
                }

                $('body').append(html_strucutre+'<br>');
            });
        }
    });
```

I know this isn't the best possible, but I'm trying to sort this one out with small steps.

First, I need to get 3 random questions 'easy_questions', with their corresponding answers (true or false). Once I'm going through 3 of those, I'll be jumping off to the next one and so on.

I did manage to get the questions and even the answers, but whenever I'm trying to exit the `$.each(answ,function(option, correct) {..}`  it's only returning one answer per question and always the last one.

What exactly is terribly wrong here?

Comment: You need to concatenate answers is what it looks like. `answers += '<span data-true="'+correct+'">'+option+'</span>'`

Comment: No need to nest utility function declarations  like `shuffle` inside other functions and callbacks

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.each` is roughly the same as the native `Array.prototype.forEach` method, which means it runs the given function once for each thing in the collection. The idea is, you use it for side-effects, once for each thing. As stated elsewhere, you could use that to push something into an array each time through the loop.

However, cleaner way if you want to **return** something from the function, would be to use `jQuery.map()` instead.

```
    var answers = $.map(answ, function(option, correct) {
        option = this.option;
        correct = this.correct;
        answer = '<span data-true="'+correct+'">'+option+'</span>';
        return answer;
    });
```

This yields an array of the same length as `answ` but containing the string built up as `answer` for each one. You could then call `.join()` to turn that into one string.

```
var myHtml = answers.join("");
```

You could avoid jQuery altogether by using the built-in `map` function of arrays instyead of `$.map`:

```
    var answers = answ.map(function(option, correct) {
        option = this.option;
        correct = this.correct;
        answer = '<span data-true="'+correct+'">'+option+'</span>';
        return answer;
    });
```